# Which (statistical) test to use for this representation of data?

Tags: clustering

After performing a specific research, I was able to group the data as follows:

`Co  Re  Ca
1   1   60
1   2   27
1   3   3
2   1   26
2   2   24
2   3   18
2   4   15
2   5   8
2   6   6
3   1   54
3   2   9
3   3   8
3   4   4
3   5   2
3   6   2
3   7   2
3   8   2
3   9   2
3   10  2`

In the data above, Co represents concepts, Re is representation cluster and Ca is cardinality. So the experiment was performed that we asked participants to propose some things with respect to three concepts. Afterwards, we analyzed for each concept what the participants proposed and we were able to cluster the data in representation clusters. So the data above actually means that for concept 1, we were able to identify 3 unique clusters and the cardinality represents the number of participants per cluster. Obviously, concept 1 was the most consistent. The concept 2 we can see that there are several clusters and the results are quite spread apart. And, even though the concept 3 has the most clusters, they are somewhat more consistent (majority was for cluster one).

So what I'd like to know is, considering the data, what kind of (statistical?) test can I perform? Ultimately I'd like to answer the question which concepts were more consistently reported.

Thanks for any kind of answer or suggestion!

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you've tried so far: (i) what was the analysis that you were planning when you first thought about the experiment? (ii) what is usually done in your field when your colleagues analyze such data? (iii) did you make a graph? etc.

Comment: When I saw the data headers I immediately knew what they meant: Cobalt, Rhenium, and Calcium of course!  (Been watching too many episodes of *Breaking Bad*...)